# How can I tell file deletion from directory deletion using JDK 7?

Tags: java, java-7, nio, filesystemwatcher, delete-file

I am using JDK 7's WatchService to monitor directories.

The `ENTRY_DELETE` event tells me an entry has been deleted. I can get the name of that entry doing something similar to:

```
WatchEvent<Path> ev = cast(event);
Path name = ev.context();
Path child = dir.resolve(name);
```

I want to know if the deleted entry was a file or folder. Naturally, I tried `child.isDirectory()` but that didn't work, of course, because the element doesn't exist any more.

Is there any way, without heuristics, telling if the deleted element was a file or a directory?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, since WatchService is built on top of the native OS's file event service, it is limited by the information the native service provides. Linux's [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) does indicate what type of filesystem object was deleted, but Microsoft's [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=VS.80).aspx) just gives the name.

Comment: Yes, I figured out that this is probably all it gets, but I thought maybe it scans the directory structure on startup or something like that, enabling it to tell files from folders when an event occurrs.

I see the reference you gave is to a .net FileSystemWatcher, but I am using Java. This .net watcher has "rename" events, which are not supported by the NIO2.0 WatchService of JDK 7, as far as I know.

Was your answer relevant to .net?

If telling file from folder deletion can't be done, I'll just have to act as if both happened - and one of my operations will fail, and I'll ignore that.